# Align and animate Entity's orientation along movement path

Tags: swift, arkit, realitykit

I am animating a RealityKit `Entity` along a path - in my case it is a straight path for the time being. I want to align the `Entity`'s orientation along the path of movement, so that the Entity "looks" at the same direction of its movement.

I have been using the [`look`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/hastransform/look(at:from:upvector:relativeto:)) function on the Entity but I encounter a couple of issues.

a) I cannot animate it and b) for some reason on some Reality Composer's Entities (the stock ones) the object seems to look backwards, as if its face is looking at the other direction (180°).

Is there any way to animate the `Entity` using the [`look`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/hastransform/look(at:from:upvector:relativeto:)) function, or even better is there a way to find the correct transform and apply it manually on the `Entity` with or without an animation?

Here follows a piece of code showing what I am trying to do:

```
let toSquare = // The target entity
let entity = // The entity to move
                        
var toPosition = toSquare.position
toPosition.y = entity.position.y
                        
entity.look(
    at: toPosition,
    from: entity.position,
    relativeTo: entity.parent)
                        
var newTransform = entity.transform
newTransform.translation = toPosition
                        
let animationDef = FromToByAnimation(
    to: newTransform,
    duration: 2,
    timing: .linear,
    bindTarget: .transform
)
let animation = try! AnimationResource.generate(with: animationDef)
let animationController = entity.playAnimation(animation)
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After some digging I found a way to do it by using quaternion math. You pass the position of the object you want to rotate, and the target is the point you want to look at.

```
func look(from source: SIMD3<Float>, to target: SIMD3<Float>) -> simd_quatf {
    let forward = normalize(target - source)
    let up = SIMD3<Float>(0, 1, 0)
    let right = cross(up, forward)
    let upDirection = cross(forward, right)
        
   let matrix = float3x3(SIMD3<Float>(right.x, right.y, right.z),
                         SIMD3<Float>(upDirection.x, upDirection.y, upDirection.z),
                         SIMD3<Float>(forward.x, forward.y, forward.z))
        
   return simd_quatf(matrix)
}
```

You then take the quaternion and you rotate the `Entity`'s `Transform`.

In order to do it in real time you need to read the Entity's orientation and position, and adapt accordingly. This can either be done within an `Event` subscriber or a `System` (or something similar).